# Failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle build failing with this error:

```
Error:C:\Users\Roman\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.0.2.aar\bab547c3f1b8061ef9426f524a823a15\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature

Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 compile failed:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 compile failed:
aapt2 compile --legacy -o C:\dev\workspace\android2\MatrixCalculator\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug C:\Users\Roman\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.0.2.aar\bab547c3f1b8061ef9426f524a823a15\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png
Issues:
 - ERROR: C:\Users\Roman\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.0.2.aar\bab547c3f1b8061ef9426f524a823a15\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature
```

Some basic things i've tried to solve this issue:

1. Invalidate caches/restart
2. Deleting gradle folder

Comment: The file `abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png` is corrupt, and is not a valid PNG file.

Comment: "Deleting gradle folder" -- which specific folder did you delete?

Comment: @CommonsWare the one at C:\Users\Roman\.gradle\caches and the one in the project

Comment: You don't say if this is a new resource or an existing one that is now showing this symptom. This is an important detail that should be in the _body of the question itself_.

Comment: @jdv what do you mean by resource? The file is located in appcompat-v7-26.0.2.aar folder, so i suppose it's the part of this library

Comment: A "resource" is anything that is not code, is in the resources directory, but is packaged into the final app. By default this is stuff in the /res/ directory of a typical Android project. But I see what you are saying. The PNG in a 3rd party is failing.

Comment: @jdv No, i didn't add any resources in the /res/ directory. Moreover i didn't add any new libraries to the build. The appcompat was there from the very start of the project

Comment: Try getting the support lib referenced from https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html instead of your local SDK. You can force it to grab a different version instead of 26.0.2 via dependencies and see if the problem goes away. Looks like your local SDK is corrupt if blowing away the IDE cache is still a problem.

Comment: You can also explode this AAR as it lives in your SDK and actually check this resource to see if it is a real PNG. This is only if you want to gather info to post a bug against what looks like a beta version of Android Studio.

Comment: I'm also having this issue and I've resaved/re-exported the file using different programs, including photoshop, to be certain it's a png, but I still get this issue!

Answer (score 151):

**It's likely a `JPG` renamed to a `PNG` file, not an actual PNG file**
The problem could be because of the wrong extension of images.
In my case, the file was a `JPEG` image but it was saved as `PNG` not converted to. In this situation change extension to the real one and convert to PNG then retry.

For instance, you have `ic_logo.png` but it's actually a JPG image.
You should rename it back to `ic_logo.jpg` and use something like Photoshop to convert the image to PNG format.

Comment: but this image is in android libraries and not for project!

Comment: @MHSFisher If you can report the developers of that library, do so, otherwise, see if you can replace the image using a standard one of your own.

Answer (score 33):

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            crunchPngs false // or true
        }
    }
}







 buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            crunchPngs false // or true

            lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 32):

### Steps

1. In `build.gradle`

```
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
```

2. Delete content inside `C:\Users\.gradle\caches` (or `~/.gradle/caches` for Mac and Linux)
3. Restart Android Studio

Comment: where to put aaptOptions?

Comment: In android/app/build.gradle -> android {  aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false  } }

Answer (score 13):

**Failed to read PNG signature - Just put 1 line in your build.gradle**

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        crunchPngs false  // Paste this line
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Creating the .apk of an application all the resources are analyzed, if some resource has an incorrect format or is corrup you will get the message:

> .png failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG
>   signature

[image]

Be sure to have the correct resources, you can check it by opening your file.

Answer (score 3):

This occurs due to the incorrect extension given to the image. **For example,** the image is ***jpg*** and the extension given is ***png***.

**Solutions:**

1. Add `{ cruncherEnabled = false }` in build.gradle
2. Convert the image into png rather than just changing the extension.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, solved by converting the images to webP from Android studio
right-click on the image -> tap on Convert to WebP

the conversion will handle file formating and also reduce the size of the PNG

Answer (score 2):

if you are facing this issue in Flutter while buildings apk  then add *crunchPngs false*

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
          ...
           crunchPngs false
        }
 }
```

into `android/app/build.gradle`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might have used a JPEG file or some other image file format.

Use PNG images to solve the error.

Drawable directory can only have png type of images.

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of wrong file type indeed and can be fixed by saving the files in correct format.

I ran into this issue with **PhoneGap Build** and wanted to leave my 2 cents for any other **PhoneGap** / **Cordova** user who might also run into this.

My problem was that I upgraded my old PhoneGap **6.x** to **8.0** and it seems behaviour of the default splash has changed. It used to require jpg as a default splash, but on 8.0 it results in this error on production builds.

This worked before:

```
<splash src="www/splash.jpg" />
```

Now you have 2 options. Replace the default splash with png like this:

```
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
```

Other option is to remove default splash entirely.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick fix ,Make **shrinkResources** to **false** instead of **true** in app.gradle
Hope this will help.
if Not then also add this *aaptOptions { cruncherEnabled = false }*

Answer (score 1):

i have same error for slow i do some step:

1. open abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00001.9.png (Image)file in paint
2. now select png and save as and re-save in drawable and overwrite the old images and it works

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any transparent pixels, then renaming the file to `.jpg` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. To solve it just restart your Android Studio and build the gradle file again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an online platform to generate App Icon(launcher_icon), then use PNG Format or First convert JPEG to PNG and then used APP ICON GENERATOR

Answer (score 1):

In my case also there was a jpg file instead of png, so I changed my extension and solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Open [Root_project]/app/build.gradle and add following lines.**

```
release {
          ...

            crunchPngs false // or true

            lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }

          ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when signing APK.

This solution fixed the problem:

`build.gradle(:app)`:

```
...
aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
...
```

You can check for more: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build

Answer (score 1):

I too got this error. This issue is due to that jpeg or other format image is in **.png extensio**n. Try to **replace the specific image with original png image**. You can also change the format by uploading it to figma and export it to **png**. [refer this image for issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qadnG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a valid solution, but deleting **only the file mentioned in the error message** helped. While deleting the folder, containing it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can add code in node_modules/react-native/react.gradle. After doFirst

```
doLast {
def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/${resSuffix}");
if (originalDir.exists()) {
File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/${resSuffix}");
ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
}
}
moveFunc.curry("drawable-ldpi").call()
moveFunc.curry("drawable-mdpi").call()
moveFunc.curry("drawable-hdpi").call()
moveFunc.curry("drawable-xhdpi").call()
moveFunc.curry("drawable-xxhdpi").call()
moveFunc.curry("drawable-xxxhdpi").call()
moveFunc.curry("raw").call()
}
```

check it if it not fix issue after remove drawable folder
github [enter link description here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26245)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it permanently.

I created a new blank expo project, then I added a new app icon (correct png format), then I ejected from expo.

I then copied the `mipmap-*` folders from the blank project to my real project. It all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I had the same issue working in macOS. Strangely it always came due to renaming a working .png file in the Finder. Simply changing the name of ic_launcher.png which worked as file to app_icon.png lead to a not working file.
I worked around it by uploading the ic_launcher.png to a photo app like photopea and simply downloading it again to my computer under the new name app_icon.png.

Answer (score -1):

You can open the images with windows win10 'Paint',
then you can save as .png and overrite it,
It will solve the problem