# app:mergeReleaseResources exception when making release build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, release-builds

I am able to create debug build but release build fails with app:mergeReleaseResources and Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: exception. 
I have tried setting progaurd off, remove any corrupted png file but still same issue is coming. Any idea what is going wrong here or how to find the reason?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved this by using this command gradlew --scan assembleRelease in terminal and it 
it gave me following error : D:\Freelance Work\InstaConnect\app\src\main\res\drawable-nodpi\blacktoblue_gradient.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start wi th PNG signature.

Once i corrected that file , it worked.

Comment: THANK YOU! This is such a hard bug to find, this was perfect. Showed me how to find the specific bug in my project

Comment: How did you corrected the file .? the mysrtie continues

Comment: @MuhammadAshfaq design or download new one and replace old one with new one in project.

Answer (score 2):

If its due to the PNG files present in the Project, then add the below in gradle.

```
aaptOptions {  
    cruncherEnabled = false  
}
```

Comment: Used this already it gave me error : add abort on lint error false.

Comment: Please  Post your Logcat also

Comment: I found the error. In terminal i used this command line gradlew --scan assembleRelease and 
it gave me following error : D:\Freelance Work\InstaConnect\app\src\main\res\drawable-nodpi\blacktoblue_gradient.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start wi
th PNG signature.

Answer (score 1):

[Failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177560/failed-to-read-png-signature-file-does-not-start-with-png-signature/59945452#59945452)

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            crunchPngs false // or true
        }
    }
}

Its Working
```