# ReactNative error "Execution failed for task"

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm new to ReactNative either Expo or ReactNative Cli. I'm getting error while this command.

`exp build:android`

I checked log from expo.

Standalone build failed!

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
[stderr] > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
[stderr]   /app/turtle/workingdir/android/sdk34/android-shell-app/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.
```

The checked my assets but they are already png files. I can't understand what is ic_launcher.png.

And also should I eject EXPO to publish my apps to App Store? I have to install some special plugins(I don't know they are only native ones...) and even Apple Payment as well. I thought complete app with expo as much as I can and eject it later. After that I can add native plugins and add payment system too. Is that OK?

Comment: check this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177560/failed-to-read-png-signature-file-does-not-start-with-png-signature

Comment: Thank you Taym. I already checked that but... I will check it again.