# Expo android build fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I'm trying to build an android app with expo build:android and it keeps failing every time even though i've tried everything on SO and google.
As I can see it says that app icon is not png but i've checked it multiple times and i'm pretty sure it is.
Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks in advance

[image: expo build log]

Comment: Maybe an invalid/corrupt PNG? Try using some generic placeholder from the internet

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177560/failed-to-read-png-signature-file-does-not-start-with-png-signature), answer your question?